# Being a permanent resident in the Czech Republic, Russian nationality. Do I need a visa to travel to the UK for 1 week (business trip)?

Tags: uk, schengen, business-travel, czech-republic, russian-citizens

I am Russian, but live for past 15 years in the Czech Republic with a permanent residency card. I have a permanent job in the Czech Republic and now I need to go on a business trip to the UK. Do I need a visa to stay in the UK for a week?

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**. Your citizenship, not residency, is what counts.

[Do I need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

Comment: Follow the given link.

Comment: @ElisUnique More than likely a standard visitor visa. As Neusser says you will need a visa but being a resident in a Schengen country will help your application massively as you have already been approved by a strict visa procedure.  https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/russia/work/six_months_or_less